# Cannot create index for new Firestore query feature "array-contains"

Tags: arrays, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am using the new Firestore query feature

```
firebase.firestore().collection("articles").where("tags", "array-contains", tag)
```

to query all the article with specific tags.

The query works fine but the result is not sorted.

I understand how database indexes work and use them with other string fields before but not yet with array type.

When I do the query

```
firebase.firestore().collection("articles").orderBy("publishTime", "desc").where("tags", "array-contains", tag)
```

It prompts a link to create index. But that link does not work.

Is this because the new feature is still under development or is there any special step for "array-contains" query type?

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: It is resolved. Now I can use the provided link to create index under type ARRAY.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now resolved by create the index field under ARRAY type
[image: New Firestore index feature]

Comment: But I still can see the error on my console + it doesn't filter out the documents.